# Should I store data in service if I have it in Database (Angular)

Tags: angular

I am sorry if this question sounds strange and if it is not smart enough.
I just wonder what is the best approach to data storing in Angular.

1 - In *service* use `http.get` and return it as observable. Then in component subscribe to it.
2 - In *service* create an array, fetch data to it with the same `http` and then use this array in my component.

Comment: There is a third one with route resolvers. call the service which implements the resolve and from activated route you subscribe to get the data. But i will go with 1.

Comment: Fetching the data is asynchronous so you will have to expose it via an Observable anyway.

Comment: creating an array has no meaning, subscribe to your observables, if you need the returned data in other component you can store it in the store (ngrx store, redux)

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on your app itself. The first option is called a **stateless service**. Its advantages that it doesn't change the state of your data, so it is considered a safer way and less error-prone. I would usually use this style. Also your browsers memory is not occupied by that data, so at some point this might become important too.

But if data is not heavy (takes small memory) and you later plan to mutate it, like filter etc. I might consider the second approach too. Because you can change its state on client (browser) without making additional queries to your database. This would most likely save you some money you pay for your server.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform some basic caching from within the service to avoid having to repeatedly fetch date from the database.

there is a great blog article on it here,

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2018/03/05/advanced-caching-with-rxjs.html

(I am no way affiliated with the link, it just really helped me!)